# Why circular reference error is occured in following code? and how to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, json

I create the JSON object , in this sample circular reference error is occured.
Why circular reference error is occured and how to resolve circular reference error?
give the full details about this issue?
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var data = { "Id": 100, "Name": "Name 1", "Children": [{ "Id": 200, "Name": "Name 2", "Children": null }, { "Id": 300, "Name": "Name 3", "Children": null }] };

        var record=createRecord(data,null);

        JSON.stringify(record);

        function createRecord(data,parentItem) {

            var record,
                childDataSource = data["Children"];

            //CLONE THE DATA OBJECT
            record = $.extend({}, data);

            record.parentItem = parentItem;
            record.item = data;
            record.childRecords = childDataSource && createChildRecords(childDataSource, record);                        
            return record;
        }


        function createChildRecords(childDataSource, parentItem) {

            var proxy = this,
                records = [],
                count = 0,
                length = childDataSource.length,
                record = null,
                childRecord;

            for (count = 0; count < length; count++) {

                record = childDataSource[count];

                if (record) {
                    childRecord = createRecord(record, parentItem);
                    records.push(childRecord);
                }
            }

            return records;

        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
record.parentItem = parentItem;
```

You add a link from the child object to the parent object.

As `JSON.stringify` iterates recursively over the properties of the objects it cycles from the parent to the child to the parent to the child, etc.

You can't exactly stringify a cyclic object. A "solution" would be to use a library ignoring the properties making cycles when stringifying, like my own [JSON.prune](https://github.com/Canop/JSON.prune). But that's not a complete solution if you want to be able to easily restore the object from the JSON afterwards.

Cyclic data structures are most often a bad design.

Comment: I misread the calls - this is the actual cause - my mistake. Great eye, dystroy! :)